# Using Elasticsearch for Geolocation with JHipster

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

I am developing an application with JHipster which is including Geolocations.
Since I can not save Geolocation Points with JHipster, I probably have to do it with Elasticsarch (correct me if I am wrong).

My JDL:

```
entity MyEntity{
    title String required,
    description String required,
    latitude Float required,
    longitude Float required,
}
```

What is the most performant way to find only MyEntities in 10km Range?
I have an endpoint

​/api​/_search​/my-entity

Where I can put a query?
But since the distance calculation is more complex how can I do it?
Do I have to index my MyEntities?

Comment: Why using Elastic? Which SQL database do you use? If you use Postgresql, postgis should cover your geolocation needs.

Comment: yes, but does Jhipster no overwrite my changes? ( I use postgres)

Comment: What do you mean? JHipster is a just a tool top help you to start, unless your project is very simple you will manually modify code generated by JHipster. To a certain degree, you can avoid this by using a side-by-side practice but in the end you will drop JHipster to focus on business value. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg5CYoBdpVo

Comment: As an alternative you can use some geo location features in java using geotools https://www.geotools.org/  without depending on a database.